# Holding information in hashtables or arrays then outputting

Tags: c#, checkbox, hashtable

I am developing a program in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and am not sure what to do about this problem.

In my program, I have a large amount of checkboxes (Yes and No) and when No is selected, a textbox appears prompting the user to write a comment, example below:

```
private void checkBox48_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      if (checkBox48.Checked == true)
      {
          // Create an instance of the dialog
          frmInputBox input = new frmInputBox();
          // Show the dialog modally, testing the result.
          // If the user cancelled, skip past this block.
          if (input.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
          {
              // The user clicked OK or pressed Return Key
              // so display their input in this form.

              problems = problems + "23. Check Outlet Drainage : " + input.txtInput.Text + Environment.NewLine;
              this.txtProblems5.Text = problems;
              txtProblems5.Visible = true;
          }

          // Check to see if the dialog is still hanging around
          // and, if so, get rid of it.
          if (input != null)
          {
              input.Dispose();
          }
      }
  }
```

However, temporarily I have the user input just writing to a `String` called `problems`. I would like to hold each of these values in separate places.

Would hash tables or an array be suitable? (For example `txtInput.Text = Problems[40]`)

Comment: A suggestion, mostly unrelated to the question.  I'm assuming that you have a `CheckedChanged` method for each of your check boxes...  If you're doing the same operation (as shown above) with just different text/controls, you should be able to make the `CheckedChanged` method generic enough so that you would only need one.  It would make your program immensely more maintainable, as well as more readable.

Comment: Have you any documentation to help me do that?

Comment: No, but in case you are not aware, the `object sender` parameter in each of the methods will hold the `Checkbox` object that the event is coming from.  That would take care of the `checkBox48.Checked` portion.  For the other objects, I suspect you would just need to make a relationship between each checkbox and the related textbox and text string.  If you want some more help cleaning it up, I'd suggest posting it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/  If you do so, comment here and I'll make some more specific suggestions.

Comment: Hey Wyatt I uploaded it http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/92549/checkchanged-event-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an array, it implies you will have to create entries for each text box as per your example.

Out of preference I would probably use a `dictionary<string,string>` where the key is the control name.
Then, my `textbox` value could be:

```
txtProblem1.text = dictionary.ContainsKey(txtProblem1.Name) ? dictionary[txtProblem1.Name] : "";
```

Answer (score 2):

Either array or hashtable will work. Hashtable may be a bit more developer-friendly and may carry smaller memory footprint. Here is a small example:

```
private Dictionary<int, string> problems = new Dictionary<int, string>;

// add key value pair
problems.Add(42, "your problem here");

// get value
string value = "";
if (problems.TryGetValue(42", out value))
{
    // the key was present and the value is now set
}
else
{
    // key wasn't found
}
```

Comment: Yeah I think I will go with the hashtable, thank you for your help